# java- Is revalidate() method necessary?

Tags: java, swing

A quick question,

Is it necessary to call `revalidate()` method each time, you change the location of components?

And what are other instances, when it is necessary to call `revalidate()` method?

Answer (score 2):

Every time you create or modify (location, size or internal content) or remove a component or multiple components, it tells the layout manager the new component list.

Yes, once you change the location, it is necessary to call revalidate().

Comment: If you change the size/location of a component that implies you are using a null layout (which you generally should NOT be doing since Swing was designed to be used with layout managers), so revalidate() does nothing. The point of using revalidate() IS to invoke the layout manager so the size/location of the components can be determined based on the rules of the layout manager. So you invoke revalidate() and typically repaint() AFTER you add or remove components from a visible container.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it necessary to call revalidate() method each time, you change the location of components?

You should not be setting the location of components. That is the job of the layout manager.

The point of using `revalidate()` IS to invoke the layout manager so the size/location of the components can be determined based on the rules of the layout manager.

So you invoke `revalidate()` and typically `repaint()` AFTER you add or remove components from a visible container.